# Speeding up Travis-CI dependencies installation for AngularJs project

Tags: node.js, angularjs, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I've just started playing with Travis-CI and I managed to run my simple unit tests in a free version.

But even on a quite simple tests set I see significant delays related to the npm/bower dependencies installation steps.

Is there a way to reduce this phase time and not install same dependencies on every build.

I read about caching support in Travis, but almost all examples are focused on Ruby so it's not really clear how to deal with JS apps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caching is only possible with Travis Pro right now, unfortunately. Travis is saying that it will open it up for open source projects at some point though :).

If you are a Travis Pro user or have `sudo: false` enabled, you can add the following to cache your node.js modules:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
```

Answer (score 3):

It is now possible to [cache](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) on public repositories if you switch to [container-based architecture](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/) by adding `sudo: false` into your config file.